# Support Vector Machine training using scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to train a Support Vector Machine using scikit-learn. It is correctly giving the output for `trainingdata1`. But it is always not giving the expected result for `trainingdata2` (`trainingdata2` is what I actually need). What is wrong?

```
from sklearn import svm

trainingdata1 = [[11.0, 2, 2, 1.235, 5.687457], [11.3, 2, 2,7.563, 10.107477]]
#trainingdata2 = [[1.70503083,7.531671404747827,1.4804916998015452,3.0767991352604387,6.5742], [11.3, 2, 2,7.563, 10.107477]]


clf = svm.OneClassSVM()
clf.fit(trainingdata1)

def alert(data):
    if clf.predict(data) < 0:
        print ('\n\nThere is something wrong')
    else:
        print('\nCorrect')

alert([11.3, 2, 2,7.563, 10.107477])
#alert([1.70503083,7.531671404747827,1.4804916998015452,3.0767991352604387,6.5742])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have to admit I actually hadn't heard about one-class SVMs before. As far as I understand, their goal is to find out if test examples are similar to previously provided example. Now, the difference between the two cases is that the two vectors are quite similar in the first, working example, and kind of different in the other one (if we compare the numeric values of the different components of the value). Could it be this is actually behaving as intended? Note that SVM training does not necessarily mean that all training examples are classified as labelled for training, due to generalization.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas78, I though there would be no explanation for my question. Your point is exactly correct. With more training example I'll try to see what is happening.